# microsoft word form entering values into a underlined field

Tags: microsoft-word

Hi I am using microsoft word 2010. While I am trying to eneter data into a field , the underline moves to the right .

[image]

Is there a way I can stop word from doing this? Which means basicall I should be able to write over the line , rather than splitting it up ?

Comment: It would be a better idea to use form fields or content controls to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Press the Insert key to toggle overwrite mode. In this mode, instead of inserting text between the underscore characters, you will replace them.

Comment: Not working mate

Comment: @misguided, What happens when you try use the overwrite mode? Does the  line move or does the text overlap?